# unable to retrieve values from two different arraylist

Tags: android, loops, arraylist

i am having two different arraylist of diffrent size,my problem is that i have to retrieve values from both the list and show that on to a textview,when i am using two loops it is first completing the inner loop and than executing outer loop and the vales are getting printed two times and if using break to break the inner loop it is completely ignoring inner loop after 1st loop.

```
ArrayList<LocationDto>location = new ArrayList<>();
education<EducationDto> = new ArrayList<>();

if (education.size() != 0) {
    for (int j = 0; j < education.size(); j++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < location.size(); k++) {
            if (!education.get(j).getSpecializationTitle().equalsIgnoreCase("") && !location.get(k).getLocationName().equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                tvEducation.append(education.get(j).getEducationTitle() + "(" + education.get(j).getSpecializationTitle() + ")" + " Located at " + location.get(k).getLocationName());
            } else if (education.get(j).getSpecializationTitle().equalsIgnoreCase("") && !location.get(k).getLocationName().equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                tvEducation.append(education.get(j).getEducationTitle() + " Located at " + location.get(j).getLocationName());
            } else if (!education.get(j).getSpecializationTitle().equalsIgnoreCase("") && location.get(k).getLocationName().equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                tvEducation.append(education.get(j).getEducationTitle() + "(" + education.get(j).getSpecializationTitle() + ")");
            } else {
                tvEducation.append(education.get(j).getEducationTitle());
            }
            if (j != education.size() - 1) {
                tvEducation.append(" , ");
            }
            break;
        }
    }
} else {
    tvEducation.setText("Not Specified");
    tvEducation.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.color_three));
}
```

what should i do now?

Comment: what's your requirement?

Comment: First check the size of list. Also change this                             `tvEducation.append(education.get(j).getEducationTitle() + " Located at " + location.get(j).getLocationName());` to                             `tvEducation.append(education.get(j).getEducationTitle() + " Located at " + location.get(k).getLocationName());`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The break statement terminates a loop regardless of whether it has completed or not, so your problem is that you've put a break directly inside your inner for loop without some sort of condition. Therefore the first time the loop runs it will reach the break which is why it's terminating on the first iteration!

You probably mean to put the break inside the last if statement?